# How can I override the standard Domino error page for a REST webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, osgi, lotus-domino

I have a webservice (OSGi application) which on failure returns the error as HTML, which seems to be the Domino standard.

[image]

I know I can use the error codes provided, but would like to return a JSON formatted error instead.

Anyone who knows how to?

Ove

Comment: I assume you are talking about a custom service. Perhaps you can show us that code so we can show you how we handle errors.

Comment: Yes.  I agree some code would be good.  Also, the HTTP status code in your original post is 401 (Unauthorized).  That response is probably being returned by the Domino web server without ever getting to your REST code.  Are you trying to return JSON just in this case (401) or for all status codes?

Comment: The detail says not authenticated. That's even before it can check for authorization.

Comment: Ok. I have found how to respond with Application/JSON content for the requests that ARE authenticated. Is there some way to tell Domino to respond with JSON instead of HTML for 401 responses?

Comment: @Ove, I don't know how to make the Domino server return JSON in a 401 response.  Doesn't mean there isn't a way, but it would be likely be done in the server configuration -- not in your REST code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the 401 response in the REST Service database you need to allow the Anonymous users to access the REST service and then in the REST Service respond if the user is Anonymous. This can be done without opening the database to significant access by Anonymous users by keeping the ACL for Anonymous at No Access BUT allowing it to Read Public Documents. Then your XPage that contains the REST service is flagged as Available for Public Access users.

Comment: But what if a user tries to authenticate but with wrong credentials?

Comment: in that case use the Default ACL setting as No Access with Read Public Documents and check the NotesDatabase.getCurrentAccessLevel(). If it is zero (0) then  no access is allowed.

Comment: Fantastic @Newbs! Saved me a lot of hassle there! Thanks a lot once again!